# SOLR - stopwords being ignored on query time

Tags: solr

I configured a field type which uses stopwords on both index time and query time. However when I analyze this field type using the analyzer, I see that those stop words and being removed only from the index side but not on the query side. Here is my field type from the managed_schema file:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="stopwords_test" stored="false">
          <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="1"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `KeywordTokenizer` on the query side. The KeywordTokenizer does nothing - i.e. it does *not* split the input string input multiple tokens. A stop filter works on tokens, and since the whole input string now is *one large token*, none of the tokens matches the list of stopwords.

Given `the input string`, this will be split into three tokens when indexing by the `StandardTokenizer`: `the`, `input` and `string`. `the` will usually be considered a stopword and removed, and you end up with `input` and `string` in your index.

When you're querying and typing in `the input string`, the KeywordTokenizer does nothing except keep everything as a single token, so the StopFilter only sees `the input string`. This does not match any stop words (unless you had the whole string as a stopword by itself), and nothing is removed.

You'll have to use a Tokenizer that splits the string into separate tokens if that's the behaviour you want, `StandardTokenizer` or `WhitespaceTokenizer` are probably good options.